# TF keras API with TF dataset problem - steps_per_epoch argument problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

When trying to fit Keras model, written in `tensorflow.keras` API with `tf.Dataset` induced iterator, the model is complaining about `steps_per_epoch` argument, even though I've set this one to a concrete value.

Here below is my model class

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from typing import Union, List
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tftools import TFTools


class TestServe():
    def __init__(self, tfrecords: Union[List[tf.train.Example], tf.train.Example], batch_size: int = 10, input_shape: tuple = (64, 23)) -> None:
        self.tfrecords = tfrecords
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.input_shape = input_shape

    def get_model(self):
        ins = layers.Input(shape=(64, 23))

        l = layers.Reshape((*self.input_shape, 1))(ins)
        l = layers.Conv2D(8, (30, 23), padding='same', activation='relu')(l)
        l = layers.MaxPool2D((4, 5), strides=(4, 5))(l)
        l = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l)
        l = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l)
        l = layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(l)
        l = layers.Flatten()(l)

        out = layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')(l)
        return tf.keras.models.Model(ins, out)

    def train(self):

        # Create Dataset
        dataset = TFTools.create_dataset(self.tfrecords)
        dataset = dataset.repeat(6).batch(self.batch_size)

        val_iterator = dataset.take(300).make_one_shot_iterator()
        train_iterator = dataset.skip(300).make_one_shot_iterator()

        model = self.get_model()
        model.summary()
        model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                      loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(train_iterator, validation_data=val_iterator,
                  epochs=10, verbose=1, steps_per_epoch=20)

    def predict(self, X: np.array) -> np.array:
        pass

ts = TestServe(['./ok.tfrecord', './nok.tfrecord'])
ts.train()
```

But as soon I start the training, before the first batch is finished, I get an exception from tensorflow

```
2019-06-13 14:22:25.393398: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 1995445000 Hz
2019-06-13 14:22:25.393681: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x2f7d120 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-06-13 14:22:25.393708: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
Epoch 1/2
19/20 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 1.0000Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestServe.py", line 62, in <module>
    ts.train()
  File "TestServe.py", line 56, in train
    epochs=2, verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks, steps_per_epoch=20) #The steps_per_epoch is typically samples_per_epoch / batch_size
  File "/home/josef/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 880, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/josef/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 364, in model_iteration
    validation_in_fit=True)
  File "/home/josef/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 202, in model_iteration
    steps_per_epoch)
  File "/home/josef/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 76, in _get_num_samples_or_steps
    'steps_per_epoch')
  File "/home/josef/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 230, in check_num_samples
    if check_steps_argument(ins, steps, steps_name):
  File "/home/josef/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 960, in check_steps_argument
    input_type=input_type_str, steps_name=steps_name))
ValueError: When using data tensors as input to a model, you should specify the `steps_per_epoch` argument.
```

The original dataset contains around 1500 samples, but I want to join multiple tfrecord files to TFRecordDataset so I wont have the information about the length.

Anyone saw something similar before? I dont know where to go for help, since the `tf.keras` API is relatively new. The `create_dataset` function just returns the dataset mapped with the right parse function.

Comment: You have two options: 1) Determine the length of the dataset 2) Instead of using tf.data.Dataset, convert the data to NumPy arrays and then fed them to the model ( you don't need to specify the steps argument ).

Comment: Why is it complaining when i specified the attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the solution.

There is not only `steps_per_epoch` but also `validation_steps` parameter, which you also have to specify.

Answer (score 3):

This error was reported when I tried to use a TensorFlow 2.0 model when I actually had an older version (TensorFlow 1.14) installed locally.

To upgrade to the latest TensorFlow version, run:

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```